# Крашится приложение при создании tab

Tags: actionbar, tabs, android

Есть TabHost, в котором несколько табов, находятся они снизу, каждый таб - это отдельная активити. В одну активити пытаюсь добавить actionbar с табами, но приложение, именно на создании таба крашится.
 код activity

```
public class Restaurant extends Activity implements TabListener {

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        //bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tab = bar.newTab();
        tab.setText("tab1");
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab);

        tab = bar.newTab();
        tab.setText("tab2");
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab);

      }
```

Лог ошибок:

```
    02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.tabsample/app.tabsample.Restaurant}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1991)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:703)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:350)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:540)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at app.tabsample.Restaurant.onCreate(Restaurant.java:23)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
02-03 16:37:43.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то TabActivity является уже deprecated и рекомендуется наполнять табы Фрагментами. А у Фрагмента не может быть своего ActionBar. Так что я думаю, это решит Ваши проблемы.

Comment: Да, TabActivity уже deprecated, но я использую просто Activity, либо уже ActionBarActivity

Comment: Что находится на 23 строке класса `Restaurant`?

Comment: Tab tab = bar.newTab();

Comment: По стектрейсу очевидно, что `getActionBar()` возвращает `null`, а это, согласно документации, означает, что `Activity` не имеет своего `action bar`'а.

Comment: Что я могу делать не так? Его, вроде как, инициализировать не надо. Или, действительно, получается, что во "внутренней" активити не может быть своего actionbar?

Comment: Гм. Что ещё за "внутренняя" `activity`?

-----

Покажите импорты `Restaurant` и `uses-sdk` из `AndroidManifest.xml`.